# Animate cell height change in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, height

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you animate a height change on a UITableViewCell when selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected)

I'd like to change the height of a UITableViewCell when it gets selected. I'm able to do this by defining

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and calling the tableview's reloadData when the cell gets selected, but I'd like to have the change be animated. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling reloadData in an animation block after you have set parameters that will force a new height?

Comment: I tried this, didn't work, although I guess it could've depending on what happens in reloadData