# Seems impossible: to animate the height change of row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you animate a height change on a UITableViewCell when selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected)

This seems like an impossible task after studying the docs from Apple. Is it possible to animate the height change of a table row? As far as I can tell, you can only animate inserts and deletes.

You can also animate things inside a table view cell (the layout etC) but you can't really animate the height of a cell (and expect the rest of the rows to animate accordingly as well). So for example, suppose row 3 just got twice as hight. I expect row 4, 5, 6 to shift down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about calling the methods that replace one cell with another in specific rows - if the new cell has greater height the process should be animated.  You can make a new instance of the same cell to replace the shorter one...

Answer (score 0):

We can animate the Table view cell on Selecting the cell and also we can increase the height of the cell..

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;


if (indexPath.row == selected_row) 
{
    return 180.0f;
}   
else {
    return 120.0f;
}
```