# iPhone - How to change the cell height of a tableview when touches it

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my table view i have different size of cells. Each cell has just some text.
When a user touches a cell, i want to increase the height of the cell and add some buttons at the bottom of the text.
Can some one tell me how can I increase the size of the cell height and add some buttons at the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Can you animate a height change on a UITableViewCell when selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected)