# Height change of UITableViewCell causes resizing of contentView and accessoryView in cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected) to animate a change of height in a UITableViewCell. I've set a UIButton as the accessoryView of the cell, which triggers the height change. The animation works fine, but if the cell gets larger in height, the ratio in width of contentView and accessoryView changes. In specific, the accessoryView gets wider, the contentView narrows. The change of ratio has got the effect, that the UIButton in the accessoryView moves a bit to left. But for me, it should stay in the same x-Position. Anyone got a clue? Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a workaround by placing a UIButton in the contentView of the cell. So solved!