# Animated change of uitableviewcell height and toggle of contents

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview with UiTableViewCells from a XIB and I want to animate a change of cell height when selected and showing/hiding some elements.
Now, for the animated change of height there's no problems, I've done it with the tutorial in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected) .
The problem is how to toggle some elements!
I can't figure out how to solve this problem! Putting on the xib the elements, they cover the cell above; by code I can't find a method to call when a cell is opened and the animation i finished!
Any ideas?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way than this, but one way would be instead of changing the cell height and adding the new components in the animation block, set a flag for that row that it should be expanded then in your animation block call

```
[tableview reloadData]
```

And in your

```
heightForRowAtIndexPath
```

method return the new cell height and in the

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

method of your delegate return the new version of the cell with the additional elements.

Comment: Yes, but with this method I lose the "beauty" of the animated change!

Comment: I think you should still be able to put the code above inside an animation block and thus get the animated effect (maybe? ... tbh I haven't tried it - I've used the above technique to adjust and expand cell sizes/content but not tried to put it in an animation block).