# Expandable TableView

Tags: iphone, tableview, expandable

How to show table view in categories and when clicked on one row it will expand with content?
I've seen it in some apps and that's how I know it is possible but can't find any reference or tutorial regarding it.

I would appreciate if someone could help me even if I don't have example code, because I don't know how to start with it.

Comment: I think this link will get you started

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be done by means of table view. I personally did this the following way: at first there was a table view with 5 sections and every section had no rows in it, only a header. When the header is clicked the sections "expands" - I add the rows to the section (insertRowsAtIndexPaths). If the section header is clicked again, I delete the rows from datasourse (deleteRowsAtIndexPaths). Hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

Go through this sample code

https://github.com/adamhoracek/KOTree

The table view will look like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdnAl.png]