# Expand UITableView cell in UITableViewstylePlain

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to expand tableview cell on it's click. There is a tableview in which two cells are expandable and others are not. I need when i click on expandable cell it should show cells under it and on clicking again it should hide. There is a image below defining this.

[image]

How can i achieve this functionality, please guide for the above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have your problem solved ?

Comment: Have you checked my Answer ?

Comment: Ya m going through it..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/) is the complete Tutorial with Expandable UITableView

Here’s the code snip for that.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

            }
            else
            {
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            }

            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i 
                                                               inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

            }
            else
            {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

as shown below picture

[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396055/expanding-table-view-cells-disappearing) one solution also help you to understand how to manage Expandable TableView

Comment: This is group table, i am asking for plain table only.

Comment: @iPhone did you check [this](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/14/iphone-uitableview-with-animated-expanding-cells/) its for plain table

Comment: I have seen such sample before posting question, this uses section expands, in plain we only one section only cell needs to expand.

Comment: @iPhone you can download sample code zip file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11290499/table.zip) which one is create for just Table's row expand, hope that helps Good Luck!!

Comment: I got your first tutorial as right and easy solution, but it is giving problem that when done with text it is ok, but i am using images on cell not text and text on submenu, they are overlapping. Why, can you help in that.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, what I'm thinking is, The titles, **Events**, **Overhead** and **Friends** would be the custom `UIView` with `UIImageView` for background, `UILabel` for title, and `UIButton` for expand. So basically

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

having return count of the titles you've.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

having return `UIView` for each titles.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

having count of the rows within that title. **You may need to maintain an array for this.**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

having height of the cell item

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

initially it should be 0 (zero) for all sections, when user tap on expand, it should be increase with respect to **number of rows * cell height** within that section.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You may need some good logic for setting all rows for expansion

Your expansion buttons actions something like,

```
- (void) expandSection:(UIButton *)sender;
```

that you can identify which section to be expand using sender.tag, so don't forget to add tag properly. You may need an `int` in `.h` file for store the current section, and can be use in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` datasource method.

Answer (score 3):

I think What you want is already given by Apple. You can take a look at [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple under the title of **Table View Animations and Gestures**.

Answer (score 2):

I have given the example source code below. You can customize this example based on your requirement.

Source Code Link : [Click here](https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController/archive/master.zip)

Output Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[JKExpandTableView](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView) is MIT-licensed iOS library that implements the [expandable table view](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView).  Be sure to checkout the included sample project as well.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by the delegate

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       //write code here
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever use this method for this purpose and can you post the samplecode for this

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is true but the link is outdated. To get that example to work you have to do extra things:

Download ExpandableTableCells project from here:
https://github.com/cocoanetics/Examples

Download DTCustomColoredAccessory.h and .m files from here:
https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTFoundation/tree/develop/Core/Source/iOS

Put the DTCustomColoredAccessory files in the ExpandableTableCells project.

There you have it a working example, it is easier to edit and move from there instead of trying to write from zero.

Comment: I've download the `Download ExpandableTableCells project` and added the  Download DTCustomColoredAccessory.h and .m files. But I'm getting an error "error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" Could you please help with it?