# How to expand collapse a custom cell in table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-cell

I have recently started learning ios app development.

I have a table, `TableViewController` with custom cells defined in `TableViewCell` . 
Each cell has a `title` as a `UILabel` and `few more labels` below it. Tapping the `title` should expand the custom cell and show a list of entries which is defined in a `UIView` named `ShowDetailView`. However I want the `ShowDetailView` to appear below the `UILabel` and above the `few more labels`.

I was able to append the view below the entire cell, however how can I achieve the above task. Any good examples/demos for the above situation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) what you are looking for? You will obviously need to tweak it to fit your needs but shows how to create an expanding cell.

Comment: check this: http://paxcel.net/blog/expandablecollapsible-table-for-ios/ i am using this for doing this type of task

Comment: use some third party it will work fine for u 1. http://code4app.net/category/tableview 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109099/expand-uitableview-cell-in-uitableviewstyleplain 3. http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/ 4: http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/expandable-collapsable-accordio-uitableview/ 5: https://github.com/DekusDenial/UITableView-Accordion 6: https://github.com/vladinecko/accordion-uitableview

Comment: Actually my cells has been customized and show title at top and few more labels and buttons below it. Show clicking on the title will expand a list below the title and above the rest of elements present in the cell i.e other labels and buttons. What you are showing is simple and I was able to do that