# Is it possible to set expandable cell inside the expandable in tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, expandable

I have tried to set expandable cell inside the expandable cell in table view cell, Is this possible to set?

My requirement is in TableView like this.

ex:

```
Name1     
    Age
       25
Name2
    Age
       27
Name3
    Age
       28
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView) for expandable cell as you want. [RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView) can expand cell as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to achieve this. You can look into these github Projects for further details :

- [SL Expandable TableView](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView)
- [Expandable/Collapsable TableView](https://github.com/singhson/Expandable-Collapsable-TableView)

Also a very good explaination of this can be found in this [stackoverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109099/expand-uitableview-cell-in-uitableviewstyleplain) post.