# Swift tableView.reloadRows deleting cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

**Requirement;**

I have a static `UITableView` and I'm trying to open a `pickerview` when one of the cells is clicked. I change the size with `heightForRowAt` so when the `cell` is clicked I need to `reload` it so that the size changes. If I use `reloadData()` it works perfectly (I want to use `reloadRows` so I can add **animation**)

**Issue:**

when I try `reloadRows(at..., with: .automatic)` the rows simply disappear. If I `reloadRows` in `viewWillAppear` nothing changes, the row does not disappear.

**Code:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)
    if colorCelllExpandedIndex != nil{
        let prev = colorCelllExpandedIndex
        colorCelllExpandedIndex = nil
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [prev!], with: .automatic)
        //tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        colorCelllExpandedIndex = indexPath
        colorCell.frame.size.height = CGFloat(colorCellExpandedHeight)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
    
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    if indexPath == colorCelllExpandedIndex {
        return CGFloat(colorCellExpandedHeight)
    } else {
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            return CGFloat(colorCellRegularHeight)
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

**Screen Images:**

[image: before and after clicking the color button]

[image: How it looks like if I use reloadData]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are some issues with functions such as `reloadRows(at:with:)` when using a static UITableView, there is a similar question in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713132/4785088) *without* resolution.

I was able, however, to update the cell height by implementing the next functions:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

So an approach you can take could be the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)
    if colorCelllExpandedIndex != nil{
        colorCelllExpandedIndex = nil
    } else {
        colorCelllExpandedIndex = indexPath
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath == colorCelllExpandedIndex {
        return CGFloat(colorCellExpandedHeight)
    } else {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return CGFloat(colorCellRegularHeight)
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

This is inspired in one of the answers provided in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276097/4785088) regarding hiding cells in static table views.