# Live resizing of UITableViewCell without using reloadData?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextview, resignfirstresponder

First of all, forgive me if the answer is already out there (I honestly have been working and searching for about two weeks).

And now, the situation:

I have a `UITextView` as a subview of a `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView`. The `UITextView` is the first responder (while user is typing).

I have it set up (through delegate protocol methods) so that after each typed character, the cell's `rowHeight` is recalculated (correctly and in the tableViews delegate protocol for rowHeight). So far everything is fine.

Then, I want that cell to be reloaded (or refreshed, whatever the term may be) *without* resigning its subview, `UITextView`, as first responder.

A non-satisfactory solution around the problem:

I am able to use `[tableView reloadData]` and then `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` to *simulate* this (so that user doesn't even notice that the textView was reloaded) and the rowHeight is perfect, but this has been causing me a lot of problems (especially with making sure that the cursor does not jump to the end every time the user types a character *and* with autocorrect forcefully enforcing its suggestions due to textView resigning).

Is there a way to redraw or resize a `UITableViewCell` (to dynamically change its `rowHeight`) without causing any of its subviews to resign as first responder?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2063776/442328) should help you. It talks about animation but im pretty sure it does what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @KDaker , but I actually saw this before and it didn't work (for some strange reason). It seems like it's worth another try.

Comment: Other answers or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: anyone? can I at least simply have a textView inside a cell and have the cell resize height on every keyStroke entered in textView? that's all I'm asking for really.

Comment: hey, hope you found a solution to your problem. I ran across [this](https://github.com/facebook/three20/) and thought it just MIGHT help you. Look at the TTTextEditor. It is a text editor that expands in size as you type. Im not sure that is going to be helpful in your cell problem but its worth a look. gluck.

Comment: Thanks! I discovered that the answer you gave was actually correct (it wasn't working in my app because I had something wrong in there). If you want, you can post the link (beginUpdates one) as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using tableView's `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` will solve this issue. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063776/442328) for more information.