# UITableViewCell Dynamic Height based on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have grouped UITableView with cells size of 400. Inside I have UIImageView with images from NSURL. How can I make those images to determine uitableviewcell height ? How can I even get real image size (at least height, it's more important than width in my case) from downloaded image ??

Its something like 9gag app. Most images would be about 3/4 of cell and almost 1/2 of screen but some images (like funny memes) where you have dialogs and which are very long should strech uitableviewcell on 2 screens (need scrolling to see whole image).

Comment: Hey You got the solution ? I am looking for the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an array to hold the downloaded images and their metadata.  This array could just be in your `UITableViewController` for simplicity sake.

When you download your images, save them into your `images` array.

Then, in your `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you query this array for the heights from the saved images - for example,

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    return [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].size.height + 50;
}
```

This will make the cells 50px taller than the image's height.  Note that you will need to [tell the table to update cell heights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063776/362730) for it to take effect.