# UITableViewCell- how to change selectedBackgroundView, default ImageView, textLabel, detailTextLabel frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating tableview with row height 100, between each row i want a 5 pixels gap. For that for each row i am adding uiview(width:320px, hight:1px) at row's 95th 'y' position . Now everything is going fine. But when i select the cell the rows selectedbackgroundview covering entire row i. But i want to set rows selectedbackgroundview height as 95.

i tried following way in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but no use, please help me out.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 95);
```

Comment: You need to reload the table and return the height in the heightForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5784367/2043580

Comment: i am using 'heightForRowAtIndexPath', for row height

Comment: You mean you designed tableview that cells show 5 px gap in between them but , when cell is tapped selection effect covers whole cell show you can see the gap?

Comment: @Bhumit: yes, when i tap the cell the selection covering entire cell(height:100px), but in this case selection has to cover 95 px.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, Finally got the solution.

We can adjust the selectedBackgroundView frame by creating the custom cell. Steps to solve the problem.

1. First we have to create class with UiTableViewCell as a Subclass
2. Inside that under `layoutSubviews`method we can change the tableviewcell related view frames        those are `selectedBackgroundView`, defalut `imageView`, `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel` frames

   **To change the selecteddBackgroundView frame**

   ```
    - (void )layoutSubviews {
   // always try to set frame in layoutSubviews
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, self.frame.size.width - 20, 88);
    }
   ```

   **To change the textLabel, detailTextLabel Frames**

   ```
       - (void)layoutSubviews {// always try to set frame in layoutSubviews
       [super layoutSubviews];
       self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20);
       self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(55, 0, 225, self.frame.size.height);

      }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Swift:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // containerView -> Is a view with constraints in the storyboard where I whish to see the selection
    selectedBackgroundView?.frame = containerView.frame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought

1. You can use multiple sections tableview pass array.Count in  `numberOfSectionsInTableView`
2. `numberOfRowsInSection` in each section will be 1
3. Pass 5px in  `heightForHeaderInSection`  so that there will be 5px gap between each of the rows
4. Pass 95 px to  `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as you want height of cell to be 95 ,
5. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `indexPath.row` you will have to deal with `indexPath.section`

Let me know if i am missing something. I think it will do what you want to achieve. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer but found the solution.

Comment: Glad you did :) Can you share it here