# UITableViewCell height animation together with content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation

I've searched on Stack Overflow and other sources but despite similar problem title I can't find a solution.

What I want to do is to animate `UITableViewCell` `height` **together** with content. Here is an example:
[image]

There is a blue panel in the middle of the cell. I'd like this panel's height to be animated together with cell itself.

I've tried 2 ways:

**First:** Changing row height and setting constraints as on the picture above:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    return indexPath == selectedIndexPath ? 120.0 : 70.0
}
```

**Second:** Setting row's height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, adding height constraint to the blue area and changing this constraint if user taps on cell.
**[Link to the repo](https://github.com/OgreSwamp/TestUITableViewCellAnimation)**

Both ways change blue region heigh **instantly** and then animate cell height. I need blue region to animate smoothly together with cell heigh, so white spacing between cells is unchanged.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28517242/4475605

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, I'll add link to the test project