# IOS Swift: How to expand table row that contains dynamic height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, row-height

my table cells are currently having dynamic heights (can expand and contract but with set constants). When click on the row to expand it, I want it to become (currentHeightOfThatRow + 50), I've been trying lots of methods but nothing works. Anyone knows how to do this in Swift? Or obj-C in IOS 8. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method and `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` after you click on the row.

Comment: That will only return a constant? I want the height return to be dynamic. For example:
Current height of Row A is 50. and
Current height of Row B is 230.

when press on each of them, I want (currentHeight + 100)

Comment: You are setting specific height for row when you select it. so you have to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and track the current selected row, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5784367/4016786) shows how to do it. If you only update the label text and want to expand the cell, you don't have to do that, self size cells in iOS 8 will calculate the height for you.