# UItableview cell not expanding to show text

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a uitableview cell. I want it to expand and show a lot of text. I set it up with autolayout and constraints. It looks right, but when I run it only shows up to two lines. I don't understand. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Here's a link to an image of the setup: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V8jetMrVDK4ebaconz9PL0y3DnJUqXmPkfyhK-0Nhbc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i think this question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2063776/2557145)

Comment: no that's when it's selected!

Comment: mine is a problem when it loads

Comment: Is that a text view in your cell? If so, have you set it not scroll?

Comment: its a uilabel  actually

Answer (score 1):

From the 2014 WWDC, with iOS 8, if you

1. Set up autolayout constraints relative to `cell.contentView`
2. Use the `estimatedRowHeight` property
3. **Dont** implement `-[UITableView tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]`
4. **Dont** use the `rowHeight` property

then you can take advantage of self-sizing cells that will expand automatically based on their content.

Check out [WWDC '14](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) under "What's New in Table and Collection Views." You'll only need to watch the first 25 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following two TableView methods

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

[Working with Self-Sizing Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) Here is a useful reference.