# Dynamically updating cell height without having to scroll Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height, cell

By default the height of my cell is set to `140`.

But if expanded, it should be set to `265`.

This is what I have:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if(expanded){
        return 265.0
    }else{
        return 140.0
    }
}
```

The problem is, I need to scroll down, and scroll back up for the cell to change height. How do I fix this?

**Secondary question** (more interested in the above question, just if anyone happens to know)

Is it possible to have the cell animate from height `140` to `165`?

Thanks

Comment: To animate: `UIView.animateWithDuration` function: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/

Comment: I've used it before, just don't know how to apply it here

Comment: Inside the closure just set the cell height to 165. It will animate by itself

Comment: what closure do you mean? Once `heightForRowAtIndexPath` returns a value I don't know how to make it animate to that value

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work here:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

It will reload the table everytime you changes something.

[Source](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/understanding-reload-repaint-and-re-layout-for-uitableview.html)

Comment: Great! Any idea if this approach allows me to add animation?

Comment: `UIView.animateWithDuration` should help there. For further informations visit [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html]

Comment: Do I put `tableView.reloadData()` inside that?

Comment: Look at this @GregPeckory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload the table view after you change anything in it like so:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

When you scroll away from the cell, if it goes off the screen it is unloaded. When you scroll back up, it reloads it. You are basically just reloading the data as scrolling would do.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Using this approach, can I add animation to the cell height change?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected