# How to update constraints on cell after I set editing on table to true?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

This is start layout:

[image]

And this is how it looks after I set editing table to `true`:

[image]

When I scroll my table down and up this looks ok:

[image]

How to update constraints on these cells once I set editing to true?

Comment: You can implement `willTransitionToState` and/or  `didTransitionToState` in your UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: and then what should I put inside that method?

Comment: Probably something like `[self setNeedsLayout]`

Comment: Method is called, but neither `setNeedsLayout`, neither `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, `setNeedsDisplay` didn't solve this. Still not refreshed.

Comment: Does the height of the cell change in editing mode?  If so then you probably need to reload the cell

Comment: Yes, the height changes. Where can I reload these cells? What method implements action just after button to edit did appear?

Comment: So this seems to be the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected - basically include these two lines of code where you activate editing mode on your table

Comment: Ok, but how to detect if that line did invoke: `tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)`? Because I have to call `beginUpdates()` AFTER this method is finished. is there any place for this?