# keyboard dismissing after updating text from tableview cell and refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

Hi i am having a UILABEL and UITEXTFIELD in a customtableviewcell.I need to update the UILABEL upon each character change.As i update the each character in the textfield keyboard is dismissing ..I even tried using Notification centre. Any quick help would be thankful

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    NSString *rateValue=[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];

    NSString *resultString = [[rateValue componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    [arrayRates replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:resultString];
    selectedTextField=textField;
    selectedTxtFieldPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
    [self.tableViewSkuVoids beginUpdates];
    [self.tableViewSkuVoids reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedTxtFieldPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableViewSkuVoids endUpdates];
    [[self.tableViewSkuVoids superview]  endEditing:NO];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"keyboardWillShow" object:nil userInfo:nil];

   [selectedTextField becomeFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: [selectedTextField becomeFirstResponder]; calls the keyboard with every call of this method 

can you call this line of code from somewhere else, here for example 
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{}

Comment: Why are you reloading the cell?  Get a reference to the label when editing begins, and update it directly.

Comment: Avi.. Have got the instance of the label its working fine ,,,But single character is read twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works for me fine

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

        NSString *rateValue=[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];

        NSString *resultString = [[rateValue componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        [arrayRates replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:resultString];

        selectedTextField=textField;

        selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];

        customCell *cell=(customCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: selectedIndexPath];

        NSString *multiplierValue=someValue;

        if ([resultString isEqualToString:@"0.0"])
            cell.txtFieldRates.text=@"";
        else
            cell.txtFieldRates.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@",resultString];

        NSString *customerValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[multiplierValue intValue]*[resultString intValue]*365];

        if (customerValue.intValue<=0)
            cell.lblCustomer.text=@"";
        else
            cell.lblCustomer.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@", customerValue];


           return NO;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you reload cell with

`[self.tableViewSkuVoids reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedTxtFieldPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

it will `resignFirstResponder` for your text field, and dismiss keyboard

Only solution is manually adjust cell height and table content height https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621733/1060785