# Can we resize UITableViewCell without reloading it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can we change the content size of `UITableViewCell` on click of a button inside it without reloading? When I do `reloadData()` or `reloadCell()` `UITableView` flickers and I want to avoid this flickering.

Comment: did you try tableview.beginUpdate and endUpdate ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063776/7104617

Comment: i think you should add a wrapper view in contenview  and then try changing its constraints on click of button. i hope this will work.

Comment: updating content and then calling beginupdate() and endupdate() worked perfectly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use **beginUpdates()** and **endUpdates()** to change content size of **UITableViewCell**, in this case **heightForRowAtindexPath** will called for each cell in tableView and update **height** of TableviewCell.
for **iOS > 10**, You should prefer **performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)** instead of beginUpdates() and endUpdates().

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

For more information

https://appengineer.in/2018/07/11/resize-uitableviewcell-size-without-fluctuation-and-jerk/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates