# how to update a uitableview cell without reloadRows and reloadData swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to update tableview cell without reloadRows and reloadData method in swift. Is It possible?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you told us _why_ you don't want to use `reloadRows` or `reloadData`?

Comment: @Eimantas I needed to update a only a particular cell and I am using my customized method set the height to the tableview based on rating given to a user. But if I give rating to single user other cells are getting impacted and same with reload rows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265234/can-we-resize-uitableviewcell-without-reloading-it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows` if you wanna just update the ones on the screen and the others will be updated through `cellForRow` / `willDisplayCell`

Then you would traditionally do something like

```
    tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows.forEach {
        if let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: $0) as? MyCell {
            cell.configure()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)    
self.yourTableView.beginUpdates()                 
self.yourTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:indexToBeReload) as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)   
self.yourTableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to update cell **content size**, You should use **beginUpdates()** and **endUpdates()** to change content size of UITableViewCell, in this case heightForRowAtindexPath will called for each cell in tableView and update height of TableviewCell. for iOS > 10, You should prefer **performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)** instead of beginUpdates() and endUpdates().

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

For more information

https://appengineer.in/2018/07/11/resize-uitableviewcell-size-without-fluctuation-and-jerk/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates