# How to increase tableViewCell height when increasing UiImageView height within the cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am banging my head around this issue for quite a time. I have a`UITableViewCell` that contains 2 `UIImageView's`. look like this:

[image]

Now the way it works is that when I slide with my finger on one of the pictures, that picture should expand it's width to the other side of the screen and it's height should enlarge to the size of the expanded width to make it even (I am using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`), which requires the `UITableViewCell` to enlarge too.

But for some reason I have not managed to accomplish this presumably simple task. and although the `UiImageView's` are enlarging as I want, but the UITableViewCell height - remains static. which results in the bottom of the cell getting hidden

Based on suggestions to similar questions asked in stack overflow, I have tried the following, yet I still cannot resolve the issue.

I have added the following snippet of code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 470
```

but not only this did not solve the problem, Now with the automatic height most of the cell is hidden and only the top is shown. seems like for some reason it requires a static row height but then again How do I cause the cell height to enlarge in response to `UIImageView` enlargement within the cell.

Comment: When using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` you should be careful to add all the vertical constraints for all the elements. Because that's how table view will calculate cell height by using constraint constants.Can you share how did you expand your image height?

Comment: the 2 images are inside of a UIView container and the view container has a constraint height and every time I pan, I'm increasing the NSLayoutConstraint outlet constant `self.picsContainerHeight.constant = self.picsContainer.frame.width`

Comment: Did you try reloading current table cell while detecting `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, or beginning tableView updates after Pan Gesture is detected?

Comment: yes. it doesn't help

Comment: are you reloading this row after pan gesture is applied to the cell ?? , 
if not try to reload the row.

Comment: yes. I added `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [self.currentIndexPath], with: .none)` but nothing changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you animate a height change on a UITableViewCell when selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `tableView.beginUpdates(); tableView.endUpdates()` at the end of animation and make sure that the cell is constrained to every edge (self-sizing cell).

This is documented in `beginUpdates` method

> ... You can also use this method followed by the endUpdates() method
>   to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell.
>   ...

Comment: my UIViews are constrained to the the Content View, but I the interface builder doesn't allow me to constrain my Cell or my Content View

Comment: That is OK. The important thing is that every vertical constraint is setted so the cell can calculate the height itself. Search for self-sizing cells on iOS. There is plenty of information.